# calculate $\prod_1^\infty k^{\frac1{k!}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, infinite-product

Is it possible to find the point of convergence of $\prod_1^\infty k^{\frac1{k!}}$

$K!=k(k-1)!$.

My attempt:

If $S_n=\prod_1^\infty k^{\frac1{k!}}$ then $\ln S_n=\sum_1^\infty \frac{\ln k}{k!}< \sum\frac1{k!}=e$

So $S_n$ is converges but I don't know if it is possible to find the point of convergence or not.

Comment: But $\log k < 1$ only for $k=1,2$, no?

Comment: @krvolok Yeah sorry I should say $\sum\frac{\ln k}{k!}< \sum\frac k{k!}=\sum\frac1{(k-1)!}$

Comment: The value of the product  is $ 1.829024680$.

Comment: @user64494 Why!?

Comment: @ mac : That was found by the Maple code $$>evalf(product(k^{1/factorial(k)}, k = 1 .. infinity));$$

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to rephrase your product as a nested radical, and sometimes these have closed-form solutions, like $\sqrt{2 \sqrt {2 \sqrt {2 \ldots}}} = 2$. However no one even knows a closed-form solution for the seemingly almost as innocent $\sqrt{2 \sqrt{3 \sqrt{4 \ldots}}}$. There all the nested radicals are square-roots. Your nested radicals are $k$th roots for increasing $k$. Thus it seems highly unlikely that anyone will be able to come up with a closed form for your expression, at least, not without some monumental effort.